# How to fix mod_rewrite problem with static to dynamic content

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would appreciate if someone can help with this mod rewrite issue. For years I had this in my htaccess, apache include files and it worked just fine.

```
RewriteRule ^/article/([0-9]*).html$ /article/article.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

But recently it stopped working. Browser shows "No input file specified." and access log shows 404 response code the requests that had to be fulfilled by the condition above.

RewriteEngine is on. This is what my htaccess mod_rewrite rules at the moment

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|map)(\?|$) /404error.php     [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/article/([0-9]*).html$ /article/article.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/relationships/([0-9]*).html$ /article/article.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples/attempts, could you please try following htaccess Rules. Please make sure to place your htaccess rules file in root and clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

##Rules for non-existing pages.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

##Rules for articile and relationship uris here.
RewriteRule ^(?:article|relationships)/([0-9]*)\.html/?$ article/article.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

##Rules for 404 handling.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|map)(\?|$) 404error.php  [L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It still returns a 404 status code and the message is the same "No input file specified."

Comment: @virap, could you please do let me know what is the sample url you are hitting here?

Comment: sure, here it is https://www.enotalone.com/relationships/2506.html

Comment: @virap, ok sure. Could you please confim if your htaccess file is residing same folder where you have `article` folder? I mean folder `article` and htaccess file should be in same level in same folder, please confirm on same once.

Comment: it was on the root of public_html. I copied to the folder 'article' but the error message is still there

Comment: @virap, no no, it shouldn't be inside article, that's what I meant it should reside same level where article folder is there, please move it back.

Comment: @virap, how about changing my rule `RewriteRule ^(?:article|relationships)/([0-9]*)\.html/?$ article/article.php?id=$1 [NC,L]` TO `RewriteRule ^(?:article|relationships)/([0-9]*)\.html/?$ /article/article.php?id=$1 [NC,L]` once? But make sure htaccess is NOT inside article its residing same level were article folder is there, let me know how it goes?

Comment: Thank you I updated the rewrite rule, removed the .htaccess from the article folder and still see the same error.

Comment: to confirm both .htaccess and /article/ are on the same level

Comment: @virap, ok sure. how about changing my rule `RewriteRule ^(?:article|relationships)/([0-9]*)\.html/?$ article/article.php?id=$1 [NC,L]` TO `RewriteRule ^(?:article|relationships)/([0-9]*)\.html/?$ /article/article.php?id=$1 [NC,L]` once? Notice, there is a `/` in new suggested rules at right side of substitution part.

Comment: @virap, Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs too.

Comment: Thank you. RewriteRule ^(?:article|relationships)/([0-9]*)\.html/?$ /article/article.php?id=$1 appears to be identical to the previous recommendation. unfortunately, it does not appear to work. I tried a different browser, external proxy browser... same error.

Comment: @virap, no its different in terms of its not starting from / and both rules are made combined ones.

Comment: @virap, ok can we do a simple testing to check if your htaccess is working or not, since you are saying its giving browser error. Put a test line like `-------` in your htaccess file and then try hitting any url if you get 500 internal error then it means htacces is enabled else its not, please do let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, adding ------- causes "Internal Server Error"

Comment: @virap, ok it means your htaccess is enabled. Could you please do give me details where htaccess is present and where your files are, samples of paths will work too, cheers.

Comment: Thank you. here are the paths for the files directories involved /home/ena/public_html/ .htaccess,  /home/ena/public_html/article/article.php

Comment: @virap, ok could you please make sure your DOCUMENT_ROOT is set to `/home/ena/public_html` path once? because 404 may come if that is not set properly.

Comment: Do you men in RewriteBase? rewrite condition, rule? all?

Comment: @virap, may be that is taken care(by default by htaccess), what error exactly you are getting, in older comments I can see its proxy error? Then it can be something else also no(like network issue etc)?

Comment: I am not aware of any network issues, I think this started happening after a switch to php 7.3, php-fpm

Comment: @virap, how about hitting a link which is non-existent? Tat will let us know if our index.php is working or not, hit any url and let me know how it goes then.

Comment: that works. a request to none existing page sends the request to index.php which properly displays the custom error page with the message.